# Lua functions: how to use tables as function arguments and self-document the code

Tags: lua

When I have functions which take many arguments it's sometimes useful to pass a single table as an argument instead of many local variables.

```
function example_1(arg_one, arg_two, arg_three)
end
```

becomes

```
function example_2(arg_table)
    arg_table.arg_one, arg_table.arg_two, arg_table.arg_three
end
```

The problem is, when calling the function somewhere else in code, it's hard to remember what `arg_table` needs to consist of. There are plenty of code-completion plugins for many editors which will help you with remembering the arguments for the `example_1` function, but not for `example_2`.

Is there any way to write the `example_2` function with a table parameter in a way that is still a table, but also shows the necessary parameters for the function inside the `()`?

something like this (which does not work):

```
function example_2(arg_table = {arg_one, arg_two, arg_three})

end
```

Comment: Start your function with `assert(arg_table.arg_one ~= nil and arg_table.arg_two ~= nil and arg_table.arg_three ~= nil)`

Comment: Why dont you simply unpack the table when calling the function and keep the function parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your formal parameter list and documentation with separate parameters, as usual.  Then document that if the first (and only) actual argument is a table, the effective arguments will be taken from the table using the formal parameter names as string keys.

Comment: And, in the implementation, this is one of the few cases where I would ever change the value of an incoming parameter: `arg_one, arg_two = arg_one.arg_one, arg_one.arg_two`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the function parameters as they are and pass a table for convenience.

For example:

```lua
function example(arg_one, arg_two, arg_three)
    -- do stuff
end
```

```lua
local tbl = {"value for arg_one", "value for arg_two", "value for arg_three"}
example(table.unpack(tbl))
```

Note that this doesnt work for tables with named keys.